# python pandas binning incorrect column format list of lists

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am working through an example to bin columns using pandas. I am trying to use the django graphos library to plot the distribution and in order to do this I need to convert the binned output into a list of lists. Below is a snippet of the data I start with.

```
         A
1     8.78
2     9.46
3     8.78
4    10.27
5    10.37
6    12.36
7    14.56
```

then I create the bins

```
bins = np.linspace(sample.A.min(), sample.A.max(), 100)
```

then I group by and count

```
groups = sample.groupby(pd.cut(sample.A, bins)).count()
```

Then I get this (first couple rows)

```
                      A
A                      
(7.68, 7.799]         5
(7.799, 7.918]        0
(7.918, 8.0364]       2
(8.0364, 8.155]       0
```

When I try to convert this output I receive only the aggregated column rows and not the bins (using groups.values.tolist()). (First couple rows)

```
[[5],
 [0],
 [2],
 [0],
 [9],
 [25],
```

My desired output would look like (list of lists)

```
 data = [
           ['Bins', 'Count'],
           ['7.68, 7.799', 1000],
           ['7.799, 7.918', 1170],
           ]
```

per the example (list example from https://github.com/agiliq/django-graphos)

For some reason I cannot get the list to format correctly I think it is due to some part in my cut example.

Comment: would this fit: groups.reset_index().to_records(index=False).tolist()

Comment: I receive this error when I try 'ValueError: cannot insert A, already exists' maybe because of the repeat of A I get after the group by

Comment: Yes do groups.colums = ['Counts'] beforehand

Comment: Thats close I need to make it a lists of lists however, also how could I add column names at this step?

Comment: my output is currently like '[('(7.68, 8.299]', 15),
 ('(8.299, 8.918]', 149),
 ('(8.918, 9.537]', 268),'

Comment: Append groups.columns as a head of your resulting list

Comment: after the list has been created or before?

Comment: When I try to do it before the reset_index I get an error stating there is a column mismatch. Could I append the columns in the reset index line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was doing pretty much what you were in the comments:

```
binList = groups.index.tolist()
countList = [count[0] for count in groups.values.tolist()] # groups.values.tolist() comes as a list of lists
binList = [[binStr.replace('(', '').replace(']', ''), count] for binStr, count in zip(binList, countList)]
binList = ['Bins', 'Count'] + binList
```

It's not the Mona Lisa of python, but...uh...great minds think alike?